# System statistics from different utilities don't agree

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, cpu, netstat

I am running an Aliyun instance with 8 vCPUs to do some high performance computing, so I want to make full use of the machine. In other words, extremely high CPU usage is not a problem; instead it is desired. The problem is system statistics reported by `top` doesn't agree with those reported by `vmstat`, `iostat`, and `mpstat`.

On the one hand, `top` says most CPUs are running at full speed.

```
top - 15:23:46 up  1:50,  1 user,  load average: 8.13, 6.01, 3.16
Tasks: 159 total,   9 running,  90 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 82.4 us, 17.6 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8167144 total,  3568996 free,   349128 used,  4249020 buff/cache
KiB Swap:   969964 total,   969964 free,        0 used.  7507044 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
23480 root      20   0   15016   5836   1680 R 100.0  0.1   4:58.51 calc
23479 root      20   0   15016   5988   1832 R  99.7  0.1   4:59.79 calc
23482 root      20   0   15016   5844   1688 R  99.7  0.1   5:00.35 calc
23481 root      20   0   15016   5996   1840 R  99.3  0.1   4:59.58 calc
23484 root      20   0   15016   5916   1760 R  99.0  0.1   4:58.46 calc
23485 root      20   0   15016   5956   1804 R  99.0  0.1   4:59.35 calc
23478 root      20   0   15016   5844   1692 R  98.3  0.1   4:56.24 calc
23483 root      20   0   15016   5984   1832 R  97.0  0.1   4:59.72 calc
 1817 root      19  -1  510308 332244 331564 S   3.3  4.1   2:01.54 systemd-jo+
18548 root      20   0   23892   3776   2124 S   1.3  0.0   1:15.34 apps.plugin
18383 root      20   0  230288  37568   3124 S   1.0  0.5   0:38.04 netdata
   40 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.04 ksoftirqd/5
   58 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:35.45 kauditd
  786 root      10 -10  137008  17812  13752 S   0.3  0.2   0:21.01 AliYunDun
  887 root      20   0 1979088  24608  11164 S   0.3  0.3   0:16.39 CmsGoAgent+
    1 root      20   0  225292   9340   6988 S   0.0  0.1   0:03.74 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+
```

On the other hand, the *stat family believes merely 15% of the CPU time is being used. Coincidentally, I have 8 vCPUs, and 1/8 = 12.5%.

- `vmstat`

  ```
  root@HPC:~/branching# vmstat
  procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
   r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
   8  0      0 3551412  29816 4235264    0    0     6   177  174  273 14  3 82  0  0
  ```
- `iostat`

  ```
  root@HPC:~/branching# iostat
  Linux 4.15.0-45-generic (HPC)   03/16/2019  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

  avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
            14.49    0.00    3.36    0.45    0.00   81.69

  Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
  vda              87.74        50.73      1418.23     376357   10521644
  ```
- `mpstat`

  ```
  root@HPC:~/branching# mpstat
  Linux 4.15.0-45-generic (HPC)   03/16/2019  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

  03:37:06 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
  03:37:06 PM  all   14.52    0.00    3.34    0.45    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00   81.66
  ```

Aliyun, the VPS provider, also confirms the CPU usage is satisfactorily high.

[image]

More statistics about the system is available at http://39.98.237.134:19999 (apparently this link won't last a long time, as I will shut down the machine as soon as the computations have been done), which is generated by [netdata](https://github.com/netdata/netdata).

My question is, which one is more accurate? Also, what makes the inaccurate ones inaccurate?